# Return info from JS array to use as a variable globally

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, google-sheets, jsonp

1st time posting here, hoping someone can assist me.

I'm still learning JS and do not know a lot about the language, I have done some google searching but cannot find a solution

My apologies in advance if this is a very dumb question or has been answered before

Here is the code that fetches info from a Google Sheet document and puts it into an array (Thanks @Z-Bone)

```
var spreadsheetUrl ='https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1XivObxhVmENcxB8efmnsXQ2srHQCG5gWh2dFYxZ7eLA/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData';
var mainArray =[]

// The callback function the JSONP request will execute to load data from API
function doData(data) {
// Final results will be stored here    
var results = [];

// Get all entries from spreadsheet
var entries = data.feed.entry;

// Set initial previous row, so we can check if the data in the current cell is 
from a new row
var previousRow = 0;

// Iterate all entries in the spreadsheet
for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    // check what was the latest row we added to our result array, then load it 
to local variable
    var latestRow = results[results.length - 1];

    // get current cell
    var cell = entries[i];

    // get text from current cell
    var text = cell.content.$t;

    // get the current row
    var row = cell.gs$cell.row;

    // Determine if the current cell is in the latestRow or is a new row
    if (row > previousRow) {
        // this is a new row, create new array for this row
        var newRow = [];

        // add the cell text to this new row array  
        newRow.push(text);

        // store the new row array in the final results array
        results.push(newRow);

        // Increment the previous row, since we added a new row to the final 
results array
        previousRow++;
    } else {
        // This cell is in an existing row we already added to the results 
array, add text to this existing row
        latestRow.push(text);
    }

}

handleResults(results);
}

// Do what ever you please with the final array
function handleResults(spreadsheetArray) {
console.log(spreadsheetArray);
}

// Create JSONP Request to Google Docs API, then execute the callback function 
doData
$.ajax({
url: spreadsheetUrl,
jsonp: 'doData',
dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

From here I would like to declare all my array items as variables so that I may use any of them in any other function on the site globally or to write it into innerHTML from any function

If declaring them as variables is not the right solution feel free to suggest anything else as I said in a beginner at JS

Thanks in advance for the help Stack Overflow Family

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the variable you want to be global as a property of `window`:

```
function handleResults(spreadsheetArray) {
    window.spreadsheetArray = spreadsheetArray;
}
```

To test:

```
handleResults([1,2,3]);

(function printArray() {
    console.log(window.spreadsheetArray);
})();
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing this correctly here but I can't seem to get info from the spreadsheet array 

Heres a link to my pen with the updated code 

https://codepen.io/mali23/pen/BqexKg?editors=1011

Thanks a lot

Comment: The code I included below "To test" is only to demonstrate that you can assign a global variable in this way. It should not adversely affect anything, but I would not include it in your production code. Other than that your code looks correct. Set breakpoints to check the values of your variables. From what I see in that codepen, your array is being stored correctly, so any issues that stem from this should be posted as a new question since it would no longer be on topic for this question.